# Limit available memory to iOS app in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, exception

I am curious if it is possible to restrict available memory to iOS app in Xcode while debugging. My application is able to record temporary videos using AVCapture and I would like to test if there is enough memory on the user's iDevice while recording and handle the exception inside `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Thanks.

EDIT: I've forgotten to mention that I am using actual device, but I own 64GB version so it can take some time to reach this limit and I expect that the end users will be younger people with 8GB iPhones.

Comment: you can send the memory message from the simulator's menu... but as for simulating device's available ram... you just have to try it

Comment: Can you not test on a device?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check available Ram (didReceiveMemoryWarning) The answer is No. iOS determinate by itself available memory. According to Apple documentation, you need to use actual device.

> Even though iOS Simulator is a useful tool, never make it the only way
>   you test an app. Because iOS Simulator is an app running on a Mac, it
>   has access to the computer’s memory, which is much greater than the
>   memory found on a device. As a result of the increased memory, iOS
>   Simulator is not an accurate test of an app’s memory usage. For this
>   same reason, always test the performance of your app’s user interface
>   on a device. In iOS Simulator, your app’s user interface may appear to
>   run both faster and smoother than on a device.

But, if you want to check free space on device - it can be done!

```
-(uint64_t)getFreeDiskspace {
    uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;
    NSError *error = nil;  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];  

    if (dictionary) {  
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];  
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
    } else {  
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %@", [error domain], [error code]);  
    }  

    return totalFreeSpace;
}
```

But keep in mind, iOS cleanup by itself iOS cache folders, when system reach certain point of free space. So, it's very hard to manually make it full.

Comment: Thanks. I've forgotten to mention that I am using actual device, but my I own 64GB version so it can take some time to reach this limit and I expect that the end users will be younger people with 8GB iPhones.